# Call to a member function fetchAll() on a non-object-

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

So, there's quite a few instances of this exact problem on this website.

But most of them have a bunch of other things mixed in wtih them, such as classes, numerous parameters, etc.

I have some very basic code, no, really, probably as basic as it gets:

```
try {

    $connection = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=desertstormweb_mybb", $mysql_user, $mysql_pass);

    $test = 'SELECT * from mybb_users';
    $statement = $connection->prepare($test);
    $statement = $statement->execute();
    $result = $statement->fetchAll();
    print($result);

} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Basically, I'm just trying to return the rows in a table, now I've used PDO numerous times before, and I've never had this problem.

I even started referencing other scripts I've done in the past and can't quite figure it out...

What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't assign the execution or you'll get the object overwritten:

```
$test = 'SELECT * from mybb_users';
$statement = $connection->prepare($test);
$statement->execute(); // invoke the execute, but don't overwrite
$result = $statement->fetchAll(); // PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
```

Comment: Brb, bashing another hole into my wall with my skull. I've literally been fiddling with this basic code for two hours and it was that simple. Thanks, I'll mark as correct in a few minutes.

Comment: @Christian.tucker hehe :D yeah those subtle things sometimes wrecks things. sure man no prob, glad this helped

Comment: Yep! Now I just have to figure out why it's returning an empty array... Today just isn't my day, the query executes perfectly on phpmyadmin, ._.

Comment: @Christian.tucker put this below the `$connection = new PDO(...)`. `$connection ->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` and turn on error reporting always

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT name, colour FROM fruit");
$sth->execute();

/* Fetch all of the remaining rows in the result set */
print("Fetch all of the remaining rows in the result set:\n");
$result = $sth->fetchAll();
print_r($result);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php

PDOStatement::execute Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure.
So instead of having:

```
$statement = $statement->execute();
```

Just use

```
$statement->execute();
```

OR

```
if ($statement->execute())
{
    $result = $statement->fetchAll();
    print($result);
}
```